# TLA+ Spec with assumptions about external systems

Tags: tla+

I am trying out TLA+ for a project at work. I want to prove that fetching data with the same key will return the same data despite some changes to the internals of the data. To do this, I'd like to model the external system as a black box whose responses have certain properties. For instance:

```
CONSTANT ValidKeys
CONSTANT DataPoints
CONSTANT FETCH(_)

\* Incorrect use of ASSUME, but for illustrative purposes.
ASSUME ValidKeys \in SUBSET DOMAIN FETCH(ValidKeys)
ASSUME \forall key in ValidKeys:
  LET fetched == Fetch(ValidKeys)[key]
  IN fetched \in Seq(DataPoints)
```

I would then like to write my own system where TLA+ would infer the behavior based on the specified assumptions. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it is better -- especially if you want to use TLC, the TLA+ model checker that's part of the Toolbox -- to use nondeterminism directly, instead of relying on an axiomatic specification using constants and assumptions that requires you to provide a *specific* instance when model checking, which is probably not what you want.

You can do this:

```
CONSTANT ValidKey
CONSTANT DataPoint

VARIABLE x

Fetch(key) == key \in ValidKey /\ x' \in Seq(DataPoint)
```

This is basically saying that `Fetch` is some operation that returns a sequence of `DataPoint`s, but you don't know which, and it doesn't matter. Now, when checking your system, it would be checked for *all* possible responses by `Fetch` (because `Seq` is unbounded, when model checking, you will need to override it with some operator that describes a bounded sequence up to some given length).

If you want `Fetch` to always "return" the same result for the same key, you can do something different:

```
CONSTANTS ValidKey, DataPoint
VARIABLE fetch

Init == fetch \in [ValidKey -> Seq(DataPoint)] /\ ...

Next == UNCHANGED fetch /\ ...
```

which says that `fetch` is some unknown function of the desired type. TLC will similarly check the spec for all possible `fetch` functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I understand correctly that ValidKey and DataPoint will have to be provided in the "What is the model?" section of the Input section?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to make them nondeterministic, you can do something similar (i.e., to say in the initial state that they are some arbitrary subset of some set).

Comment: Oh, I see. That's useful. Thanks a lot! Also, I since I think you're the author of TLA+ in Practice and Theory, thanks very much; it's a great reference!